# Looping through worksheets and check cell value

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to loop through all sheets and check them one by one and do the following: If in the checked cell the value of E18 = N/A then on the first sheet (named Summary) I'd change the value of G23 to N/A as well (and then do that for each cell, and on Summary change G23 then G24 then G25 and so forth) I wrote the following loop, it runs but it doesn't do anything whatsoever

```
Sub MyTestSub()

Dim ws As Worksheet

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
For X = 22 To LastRow
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Range("E18").Value="N/A" then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("G"&x).Value="N/A"
    Next ws                 
Next x

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to comment my answer or Vityata ?

Comment: Tried to comment yours haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be a 2-Step procedure:

1. Check if `IsError` in the cell.
2. Check if the type of error is `#N/A`, with `If .Range("E18").Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then`.

Otherwise, if you have a regular `String`, like "Pass" you will get an error.

**Code**

```
Dim lRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Sheets("Summary").Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
lRow = 23 ' start from row 23

For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Name <> "Summary" Then
            If IsError(.Range("E18").Value) Then
                If .Range("E18").Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
                    Sheets("Summary").Range("G" & lRow).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next ws
```

Comment: how would I go about using this method to loop through all the worksheets though?

Comment: @Rhyfelwr is `LastRow` looked in every sheet ? or just "Master" ?

Comment: Basically E18 is a constant, it always contains a value (Pass/Fail or N/A) on all worksheets except Summary I'd only check what value E18 contains, and if it contains N/A then I'd also want to change the value of G23 to N/A for the first sheet examined, then G24 for the second and so on, hence the need for LastRow.

Comment: @Rhyfelwr try edited code, see if this what you wanted

Comment: sadly it still doesn't do it. I mean that E18 contains the string N/A as is, I see that xlErrNa is different in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reverse the nested loops. Something like this should be working:

```
Sub MyTestSub()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row            
        If IsError(ws.Range("E18")) then 
            For X = 22 To LastRow
                Sheets("Summary").Range("G" & LastRow) = ws.Range("E18")
            next x
        end if
    Next ws                 
End Sub
```

Furthermore, I assume that the `LastRow` is different per worksheet, thus you have to reset it quite often - every time there is a new worksheet.
Last but not least - make sure that you refer the worksheet, when you are refering to `Cells`, like this:

```
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
```

If you do not do it you will be taking into account the `ActiveSheet`.

Here is more about the errors in Excel and returning them - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx

The solution will work with any error, not only with *#N/A*

Comment: `If ws.Range("E18").Value="N/A" then` won't find cells with `#N/A`, you need to use `CVErr(xlErrNA)`

Comment: LastRow is only relevant for the "Summary" sheet, all the other worksheets are newly generated and they are standardized forms (meaning that cell E18 will always contain a value that is Pass/Fail or N/A). Now that you say it I am not even sure if LastRow is necessary as all, I am just trying to make it so that the values found on the worksheets will change always the next row for each sheet to N/A on "Summary" sheet. It's a bit hard to explain haha

Comment: @ShaiRado - true, still I was thinking about a string.

Comment: FWIW - the `For X = 22 To LastRow` loop is just doing the same thing `LastRow - 21` times.  (The inside of the loop isn't dependent on `X`.)